# Fourier Transform of an impulse function

Tags: solution-verification, fourier-transform

We have to find the Fourier transform of the following impulse response
$$
h(t)=T[\delta (t)]=\frac{1}{2t_{d}}(\delta (t+t_{d})-\delta (t-t_{d}))
$$

My own approach led to the following:
$$
H(\omega )=\frac{1}{2t_{d}}\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }(\delta (t+t_{d})-\delta (t-t_{d}))e^{-i\omega t}dt
$$
$$
H(\omega )=\frac{1}{2t_{d}}\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }(\delta (t+t_{d})e^{i\omega t_{d}}-\delta (t-t_{d})e^{-i\omega t_{d}})dt
$$
$$
H(\omega )=\frac{1}{2t_{d}}(e^{i\omega t_{d}}-e^{-i\omega t_{d}})
$$
This however is wrong and the result should have been
$$
H(\omega )=\frac{1}{2t_{d}}(e^{i\omega t_{d}}+e^{-i\omega t_{d}})
$$
I don't know what I did wrong so if anyone could show me that would help a lot.

Comment: Why do you think the last result is the correct one? Please cite the source.

Comment: Can't cite the source since it's a locked document but the exercise is from one of the former exams that were given out and the last result was the answer but there was no clear explanation or calculation given.

Comment: OK. You did nothing wrong. Your result is the correct one.

Comment: Perhaps the answers to "exercise ... from one of the former exams" have a misprint.  That is more likely than misprints in a textbook, and certainly those have happened, too.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same result as you:
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \big(\delta (t+t_d)  - \delta(t-t_d) \big)e^{-i\omega t} dt = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta (t+t_d) e^{-i\omega t} dt -  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(t-t_d) e^{-i\omega t} dt. $$ Then by doing changes of variables $u=t+t_d$ and $u=t-t_d$, you can express the integral as
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta (u) e^{-i\omega (u-t_d)} du -  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(u) e^{-i\omega (u+t_d)} du  = e^{i\omega t_d} - e^{-i\omega t_d}.$$